# Missing Details form on custom shipping method/service

Tags: commerce, hooks

In Drupal 7, I created custom shipping service which doesn't calculate any rate but collects customer account number for Fedex or UPS on the cart page when a specific shipping method is selected.

```php
$ups_shipping['ups_ground_collect'] = [
  'title' => t('UPS Ground collect'),
  'shipping_method' => 'custom_shipping',
  'price_component' => '...',
  'callbacks' => [
    'rate' => 'cde_ups_3dayair_rate',
    'details_form' => 'cde_shipping_service_details_form',//(Added field here)
    'details_form_validate' => 'cde_shipping_service_details_form_validate',
    'details_form_submit' => 'cde_ups_ground_collect_form_submit',// (saved field data in db)
  ],
];
```

> [image: Flat rate]

> [image: Collect UPS account number]

> [image: Collect fedex account number]

In the Drupal 9 shipping method plugin, I am only able to add configuration form and not user details_form to show custom form to customer on Cart page and collect data for specific shipping method.